# How to browse a registry hive file?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, regedit

I had to reinstall windows but forgot to backup settings from an app from the registry.
I still have the old registry in Windows.old/Documents and Settings/me. I think it's the ntuser.dat file. Is there any way to browse this file like you do with regedit, so I can get my settings?

Comment: nvm found this http://www.gaijin.at/en/dlregview.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `regedit`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Click the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` key.
3. Click the **File > Load Hive** menu, and select the registry hive file (eg. `NTUSER.DAT`).
4. Choose an unique name, and click **OK**.

The registry hive will be available inside the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` key, ready to be explored. When you're done, click **File > Unload Hive**.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to remove the new unwanted registry keys; Download notepad++ , the portable one from the official website and place in folder on root of your main drive (C:\np)
Write down the path to the unwanted registry or copy paste the path in a text file on the root of your main drive (C:\path.txt)

you'll have to boot into recovery mode
Power off -> F8F8F8F8 -> repair your computer
Now go for command prompt
Depending on what screen you are on
Keyboard -> user -> (if auto repair shows) cancel -> yes -> advanced recovery options -> command prompt
Type these seperately
Cd \ -> cd np -> dir -> (you'll want the main executable for np)
Now with that open
File open
Browse to
C:\windows\system32\config
And you'll have to do some snooping, but your goal is to find the unwanted registry keys. That's why I had you copy the path earlier, because this part goes so much smoother.
You'll have to open each file that has to do with user. Not system not security and not Sam. Once found. DON'T DELETE ANYTHING!!!!!
go back into cmd without closing np -> copy (registry hive file name)  (registry hive file name).bak
Now you can delete the unwanted keys, save and exit np, close cmd and restart. You can check that the keys are if fact gone through regedit. If they are still there then you'll have to do the same thing with one of the other registry files.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is possible.

Open up registry editor.

Click `File` > `Import`.

Change the dropdown to `Registry Hive Files (*.*)`, and select your `ntuser.dat` file.

When it asks for a name to mount as, choose something like "temp registry mount".

Find what you want and when you are done, right click and choose `Unload Hive`.

All done!

Comment: it doesn't appear in the list

Comment: k I managed to unhide the file but when I load it in the registry editor it says "The key will be restored on top of key: Computer. All value entries and subkeys of this key will be deleted. Do you want to continue the operation?" Heck no, I dont want to overwrite the current registry :/

Comment: -1 because I *imported* the registry into a subkey I created (HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Environment\MyHiveLoad) but then I was not able to "Unload" it because buttons for unload it are disabled on that branch (and because it was imported not loaded). Then I tried deleting them, and it deleted many of the keys, but many cannot be deleted (throws errors when deleting)
So now I don't know how to fix it.